# Problems with proof by induction $\frac1{1\times2} + \frac1{2\times3} + \dots + \frac1{n(n+1)} = \frac1{n+1}$?

Tags: summation, induction

> $$\frac1{1\times2} + \frac1{2\times3} + \dots + \frac1{n(n+1)} = \frac1{n+1}$$

Prove for $n=1$: $$\frac1{1\times2}=\frac1{1+1}=\frac12$$

Hip: $$\frac1{1\times2} + \frac1{2\times3} + \dots + \frac1{n(n+1)} = \frac1{n+1}$$

Demonstration: $$\frac1{n+1} + \frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}=\dots=\frac1{(n+1)+1}$$
My problem is that I can't find the correct algebra steps to get from the beginning of the demonstration to the end of the demonstration.

Comment: Are you familiar with how induction works? If you are, it appears you have almost all of the work that would be needed.

Comment: You may be struggling because the sum is $\frac{n}{n+1}$, not $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Since the thing you are trying to prove is false (as Theo observed), you should ask yourself: what should you **really** be trying to prove.

Comment: Okay. Thanks everybody. So the problem might be the formula as Bendit said?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is incorrect. The correct answer should be $1-\frac1{n+1}$.

We can show that the above is true for $n=1$ easily. Now let us show $1-\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}=1-\frac1{n+2}$

We can prove that $\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2}=\frac {n+2}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac {n+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{n+2-n-1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}$ and vice versa. The $\frac1{n+1}$ terms cancel out, giving us $1-\frac1{n+2}$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {1}{1\times 2}=1-1/2$

$\frac{1}{2\times 3}=1/2 - 1/3$

........

$\frac {1}{n(n+1)} =1/n- \frac {1}{n+1}$

Add them up and cancel the middle terms to get $1-\frac {1}{n+1}=\frac {n}{n+1}$

Answer (score 0):

You can see immediately that
what you have stated is false
because the left side increases
with increasing n
while the right side decreases.

So,
you have to find out
what you really want to prove.